# Detect UITableView Index Touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created an indexed table view by implementing `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` I want to have some UI which shows which index the user is currently selecting. I have the UI working but want to hide it once the user stops touching the screen. Is there any way to detect this touch event? No matter what I try I cannot seem to detect touches in the index view

So far I have tried

Overriding the touchesEnded method of the view controller

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    self.indexPreviewContainer.hidden = YES;
}
```

Adding a Pan gesture recognizer to the view controller view, window, table view and the table view's sub views. It has this as it's action method

```
-(void)tablePanned:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        self.indexPreviewContainer.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Extending UITableView and overriding the touchesEnded method. This gave feedback as to when the table was touched but not the indices. The implementation was the same as for the view controller.

I'm guessing that the index view doesn't get added until some time after `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` method is called. I'm not sure how I'd hook into the lifecycle of the table view to test this

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: u can use UITouch delegate methods to detect if user is touching the screen or not!